# Select objects based on value of variable in object using jq

Tags: json, bash, select, jq

I have the following json file:

```
{
    "FOO": {
        "name": "Donald",
        "location": "Stockholm"
    },
    "BAR": {
        "name": "Walt",
        "location": "Stockholm"
    },
    "BAZ": {
        "name": "Jack",
        "location": "Whereever"
    }
}
```

I am using jq and want to get the "name" elements of the objects where 'location' is 'Stockholm'.

I know I can get all names by

```
cat json | jq .[] | jq ."name"
"Jack"
"Walt"
"Donald"
```

But I can't figure out how to print only certain objects, given the value of a sub key (here: `"location" : "Stockholm"`).

Answer (score 708, accepted):

Adapted from this post on [Processing JSON with jq](https://zerokspot.com/weblog/2013/07/18/processing-json-with-jq/), you can use the [`select(bool)`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#select(boolean_expression)) like this:

```sh
$ jq '.[] | select(.location=="Stockholm")' json
{
  "location": "Stockholm",
  "name": "Walt"
}
{
  "location": "Stockholm",
  "name": "Donald"
}
```

Comment: How would I get the parent 'FOO', 'BAR', 'BAZ'?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by parent (do you mean key?)... it's just `jq 'keys' json`. If you meant the keys after the filter, giving `"FOO" "BAR"`, use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31911811/6243352) and use `.key` instead of `[.key, .value.name]`.

Comment: why aren't the commas preserved between the elements?

Answer (score 319):

To obtain a stream of just the names:

```
$ jq '.[] | select(.location=="Stockholm") | .name' json
```

produces:

```
"Donald"
"Walt"
```

To obtain a stream of corresponding (key name, "name" attribute) pairs, consider:

```
$ jq -c 'to_entries[]
        | select (.value.location == "Stockholm")
        | [.key, .value.name]' json
```

Output:

```
["FOO","Donald"]
["BAR","Walt"]
```

Comment: He wants the whole object based on location: "I can't figure out how to print only certain objects, given the value of a sub key"

Comment: You don't need the pipe after selection: $ jq '.[] | select(.location=="Stockholm").name' json

Comment: Making the `name` key variable (use a shell function with `$1` as parameter) does not work: `termux-contact-list |jq -r '.[] | select(.name=="$1")|.number'`. I call it like `cool_fn Name1`. However, this works: `termux-contact-list |jq -r '.[] | select(.name=="Name1")|.number'`

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40027637/1705829) is the solution if you like it variable.

Comment: @Fo - In the body of the question, the OP was quite specific: 'I want to get the "name" elements of the objects'.  Evidently, in the title of the Q, the OP was using the word "objects" in a generic sense.

Comment: Is there a way sort the output i.e. 
`["FOO","Donald"]
 ["BAR","Walt"]` as 
`["BAR","Walt"]
["FOO","Donald"]`

Comment: Yes. Use `sort` or `sort_by`.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to add prefix to the selected KEY? e.g, add `MY_` as prefix to the parent name, say change `FOO` to `MY_FOO` in the above example.

Comment: @rodee - Yes, it’s trivial. Use string addition on `.key`

Answer (score 61):

I had a similar related question:  What if you wanted the original object format back (with key names, e.g. FOO, BAR)?

Jq provides `to_entries` and `from_entries` to convert between objects and key-value pair arrays.  That along with `map` around the select

> These functions convert between an object and an array of key-value
>   pairs. If to_entries is passed an object, then for each k: v entry in
>   the input, the output array includes {"key": k, "value": v}.
>
> from_entries does the opposite conversion, and with_entries(foo) is a
>   shorthand for to_entries | map(foo) | from_entries, useful for doing
>   some operation to all keys and values of an object. from_entries
>   accepts key, Key, name, Name, value and Value as keys.

```
jq15 < json 'to_entries | map(select(.value.location=="Stockholm")) | from_entries'

{
  "FOO": {
    "name": "Donald",
    "location": "Stockholm"
  },
  "BAR": {
    "name": "Walt",
    "location": "Stockholm"
  }
}
```

Using the `with_entries` shorthand, this becomes:

```
jq15 < json 'with_entries(select(.value.location=="Stockholm"))'
{
  "FOO": {
    "name": "Donald",
    "location": "Stockholm"
  },
  "BAR": {
    "name": "Walt",
    "location": "Stockholm"
  }
}
```

Comment: One thing that keeps biting me is that you need to remember that when using `with_entries()`, you usually want to also use `.value` in the `select` clause. This is because the `to_entries` macro converts the given entries to `.key` and `.value` pair, which also happens with `with_entries`.

Answer (score 38):

Just try this one as a full copy paste in the shell and you will grasp it.

```
# pass the multiline string to the jq, use the jq to 
# select the attribute named "card_id" 
# ONLY if its neighbour attribute
# named "card_id_type" has the "card_id_type-01" value.
# jq -r means give me ONLY the value of the jq query no quotes aka raw


cat << EOF | \
    jq -r '.[]| select (.card_id_type == "card_id_type-01")|.card_id'
    [  
     { "card_id": "id-00", "card_id_type": "card_id_type-00"},
     { "card_id": "id-01", "card_id_type": "card_id_type-01"},
     { "card_id": "id-02", "card_id_type": "card_id_type-02"}
    ]
EOF
# this ^^^ MUST start first on the line - no whitespace there !!!
# outputs:
# id-01
```

or with an aws cli command

```
 # list my vpcs or
 # list the values of the tags which names are "Name" 
 aws ec2 describe-vpcs | jq -r '.| .Vpcs[].Tags[]
        |select (.Key == "Name") | .Value'|sort  -nr
```

Note that you could move up and down in the hierarchy both during the filtering phase and during the selecting phase :

```
 kubectl get services --all-namespaces -o json | jq -r '
 .items[] | select( .metadata.name 
     | contains("my-srch-string")) | 
     { name: .metadata.name, ns: .metadata.namespace 
     , nodePort: .spec.ports[].nodePort
     , port: .spec.ports[].port}
 '
```

Comment: I dont understand why this least voted, and not accepted, comment is at the top?

Comment: check your personal settings for sorting the answers ... it might be based on last modified ts ;o)

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this helps others,   ive used jq in 100s of my own scripts,
but i fight with using vars in it every single time...  in this case below was only way i could get a number var to pass to it (ie single quotes around the arg/var):

```
id=26533

cat mydata.json | jq -r --arg id "$id" '.sensor[] |
select(.objid=='$id').probe'
```