# How to parse parameter's name from JSON with python

Tags: python, json, bash

I want to parse in bash the json-string like this:

```
{"710":{"sysKey":"ENTER"},"230":{"sysKey":"DELETE"},"804":{"sysKey":"ADD"}}
```

My task is to find the value of key `{"sysKey":"DELETE"}` and get `230`

My try:

```
echo '{"710":{"sysKey":"ENTER"},"230":{"sysKey":"DELETE"},"804":{"sysKey":"ADD"}}' | python -c 'import json,sys;obj=json.load(sys.stdin);print obj["sysKey"]["DELETE"];'
```

Help me please!

Comment: So are you limited to bash or can you use python? Your tags are confusing.

Comment: I can use python in bash commands like this: echo '{"key":"value"}' | python -c 'import json,sys;obj=json.load(sys.stdin);print obj["key"];'

Comment: if you can advice me how to parse this string without python, I would be very grateful

Comment: `230` is the key not the value. You can't lookup by value. You need to walk for values. So you get to walk all the values looking for a value that is a dictionary with a `sysKey` key that has `DELETE` as its value.

Comment: Look into the `jq` utility. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18592173/select-objects-based-on-value-of-variable-in-object-using-jq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only 'DELETE' you will pipe in is the one under 'sysKey', you could do this:

```
echo '{"710":{"sysKey":"ENTER"},"230":{"sysKey":"DELETE"},"804":{"sysKey":"ADD"}}' | python -c 'import json,sys;obj=json.load(sys.stdin);obj=dict((z,x) for x, y in obj.items() for z in y.values());print obj["DELETE"];'
```

But that's pretty ugly by just about anybody's standard, I think...

Comment: on the advice of Etan Reisner, my decision was:
`echo {"710":{"sysKey":"ENTER"},"230":{"sysKey":"DELETE"},"804":{"sysKey":"ADD"}} | python -c $'import json,sys;obj=json.load(sys.stdin);\nfor key in obj.keys():\n\tif obj[key]["systemName"]=="DELETE":  print key'`