# Using jq to search value of a property and return another value

Tags: json, command-line, jq

Sorry if this sounds too simple but I am still learning and have spent few hours to get a solution. I have a large json file and I would like to search a specific value from an object and return value from other object.

Example, from the below data, I would like to search the json file for all objects that have value in unique_number that match "123456" and return this value along with the IP address. 
jq should return something like - `123456, 127.0.0.1`
Since the file is going to be about 300 MB with many IP addresses will there be any performace issues?

Partial json -

```
{
  "ip": "127.0.0.1",
  "data": {
    "tls": {
      "status": "success",
      "protocol": "tls",
      "result": {
        "handshake_log": {
          "server_hello": {
            "version": {
              "name": "TLSv1.2",
              "value": 1111
            },
            "random": "dGVzdA==",
            "session_id": "dGVzdA==",
            "cipher_suite": {
              "name": "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
              "value": 1122
            },
            "compression_method": 0,

          },
          "server_certificates": {
            "certificate": {
              "raw": "dGVzdA==",
              "parsed": {
                "version": 3,
                "unique_number": "123456",
                "signature_algorithm": {
                  "name": "SHA256-RSA",
                  "oid": "1.2.4.5.6"
                },
```

Comment: does jq stand for jquery?
Is it the way you use jquery to get to work with the json:
`var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonString);`
Could you please provide some examples on how you do it. Thanks!

Comment: jq is command line processor for json. See this - https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select objects based on value of variable in object using jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18592173/select-objects-based-on-value-of-variable-in-object-using-jq)

Comment: Please give a more informative and more succinct example in accordance with the [mcve] guidelines. The sample JSON should be valid.

Answer (score 0):

The straight-forward way would be to use the [`select` filter](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#select(boolean_expression)) (either standalone on multiple values or with `map` on an array) and filter all objects matching your criterion (e.g. equal to `"123456"`) and then transform into your required output format (e.g. using string interpolation).

```
jq -r '.[]
| select(.data.tls.result.handshake_log.server_certificates.certificate.parsed.unique_number=="123456")
| "\(.ip), \(.data.tls.result.handshake_log.server_certificates.certificate.parsed.unique_number)"'
```

Because the `unique_number` property is nested quite deeply and cumbersome to write twice, it makes sense to first transform your object into something simpler, then filter, and finally output in the desired format:

```
jq -r '.[]
| { ip, unique_number: .data.tls.result.handshake_log.server_certificates.certificate.parsed.unique_number }
| select(.unique_number=="123456")
| "\(.ip), \(.unique_number)"'
```

Alternatively using `join`:

```
.[]
| { ip, unique_number: .data.tls.result.handshake_log.server_certificates.certificate.parsed.unique_number }
| select(.unique_number=="123456")
| [.ip, .unique_number]
| join(", ")
```