# How do I check the status of my most recently completed Codebuild build projects?

Tags: jq, aws-codebuild

How do I check the status of my most recent AWS Codebuild build projects using the CLI? I see that you can [view the build details](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/view-build-details.html#view-build-details-cli), but it requires a specific build-id, and the [summarized build information](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/getting-started-cli-monitor-build.html#getting-started-cli-monitor-build-cli) does not give any details on which build phase is correlated to the status that appears in the console.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can approach the problem in two steps:

1. Get the id of the most recent build with [`list-builds-for-project`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/codebuild/list-builds-for-project.html)
2. Select the relevant field from the output of [`batch-get-builds`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/codebuild/batch-get-builds.html)

Assuming you have `aws` CLI and `jq` installed, and are receiving CLI results in JSON format:

```
id=$(aws codebuild list-builds-for-project --project-name myproject | jq -r '.ids[0]')
```

The default sort order puts the most recently completed build at the top of the list. Then use `$id` from the prior step:

```
aws codebuild batch-get-builds --ids "$id" | jq '.builds[].phases[] | select (.phaseType=="BUILD") | .phaseStatus'
```

See [select objects based on value of variable in object using jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18592173/select-objects-based-on-value-of-variable-in-object-using-jq) for a discussion of the jq syntax.

Comment: In the first step, you could write `jq '.ids[0]'` (saving the call to `head`).

Comment: Great idea, @peak; I was also able to remove the call to `tr` by asking `jq` for raw output with `-r`

Comment: You can also get the build ID from `start-build` using the `jq` expression `jq -r '.build.id'`

Answer (score 1):

I may have reinvented or over-engineered the wheel, but wrote a little node program to do this that might be of use to you.

```js
const { exec } = require("child_process");
const { promisify } = require("util");

const asyncExec = promisify(exec);

const getLatestBuildId = async () => {
  const listBuildsCommand = "aws codebuild list-builds";
  const { stdout } = await asyncExec(listBuildsCommand);
  const { ids } = JSON.parse(stdout);
  const [latestBuildId] = ids;
  return latestBuildId;
};

const getBuildStatus = async (latestBuildId) => {
  const batchGetBuildsCommand = `aws codebuild  batch-get-builds --ids ${latestBuildId}`;
  const { stdout } = await asyncExec(batchGetBuildsCommand);
  const { builds } = JSON.parse(stdout);
  const [latestBuild] = builds;
  const { id, currentPhase, buildStatus, startTime, endTime } = latestBuild;
  return {
    id,
    currentPhase,
    buildStatus,
    start: new Date(startTime * 1000).toLocaleTimeString(),
    end: new Date(endTime * 1000).toLocaleTimeString(),
  };
};

const reportBuildStatus = async () => {
  const latestBuildId = await getLatestBuildId();
  const latestBuild = await getBuildStatus(latestBuildId);
  console.log(latestBuild);
};

reportBuildStatus();
```