# how to output all the keys and values from json using jq?

Tags: json, yaml, key, jq, pipeline

I am trying to out all the data from my json file that matches the value "data10=true" it does that but only grabs the names, how can i make it so it will output everything in my json file with anything that matches the "data10=true"?

this is what ive got       `data=$(jq -c 'to_entries[] | select (.value.data10 == "true")| [.key, .value.name]' data.json )`

This is in my YAML template btw, running it as a pipeline in devops.

Comment: Can you provide some input and required output samples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The detailed requirements are unclear, but hopefully you'll be able to use the following jq program as a guide:

```
..
| objects
| select( .data10 == "true" )
| to_entries[]
| select(.key != "data10")
| [.key, .value]
```

This will recursively (thanks to the initial `..`) examine all the JSON objects in the input.

### p.s.

If you want to make the selection based on whether .data10 is `"true"` or `true`, you could change the criterion to `.data10 | . == true or . == "true"`.

Comment: I have a file called data.json in github and I am calling this file from my YAML template

---
trigger:
  - none
pool:
  name: Hosted Ubuntu 1604
steps:
  - script: |
      displayName: 'Update the build number in readme.txt' 
      name: JQ
      sudo apt-get install jq
      echo 'installing jq'
      curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/test/data.json?token=234234234324423edvfg
      data=$(jq .. objects | select( .data10 == true ) | to_entries[] | select(.key != "data10") | [.key, .value]' data.json)
running this i am getting an error: syntax error: unexpected end of file.

Comment: You seem to be missing the first pipe symbol and the necessary single-quotes.  If you're going to include the jq program on the command line, the invocation should look like: `jq '.. | objects .......' data.json`

Comment: Thanks peak seems it passed but i am not getting any values back..this is my data.json file:{
    "FOO": {
        "data10":"true",
        "name": "Donald",
        "location": "Stockholm"
    },
    "BAR": {
        "data10":"true",
        "name": "Walt",
        "location": "Stockholm"
    },
    "BAZ": {
        "data10":"true",
        "name": "Jack",
        "location": "Whereever"
    }
}

Comment: My mistake.  I wrote `true` instead of `"true"`. Changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
jq 'to_entries | map(select(.value.data10=="true")) | from_entries' data.json
```

input ***data.json***,
with **false** value:

```
{
  "FOO": {
    "data10": "false",
    "name": "Donald",
    "location": "Stockholm"
  },
  "BAR": {
    "data10": "true",
    "name": "Walt",
    "location": "Stockholm"
  },
  "BAZ": {
    "data10": "true",
    "name": "Jack",
    "location": "Whereever"
  }
}
```

output:

```
{
  "BAR": {
    "data10": "true",
    "name": "Walt",
    "location": "Stockholm"
  },
  "BAZ": {
    "data10": "true",
    "name": "Jack",
    "location": "Whereever"
  }
}
```

based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37843822/983325

Comment: @rayaurelius - If it’s perfect, it would be appropriate to upvote it.