# Display an object if a nephew element array contains a value

Tags: json, select, jq

[Select objects based on value of variable in object using jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18592173/select-objects-based-on-value-of-variable-in-object-using-jq)

That shows how to return values directly above the selection criteria but how would I get another object that was adjacent to a value above my selection criteria?

Given the data below, what jq invocation would return the French name of planets whose moon(s) have been spoiled?   (this is a structural reproduction of the live data with which I am working -- which actually uses the word "value" in this way, so that's not helping)

```
{"kind":"solarsystem","name":"Sol",
"Planets": [
 { "kind":"habitable",
  "names": { "english":"Earth","french":"Terre"},
  "satellites" : [
    {"name":"The Moon",
     "parameters": [
       {"name":"diameter", "intValue":"3476"},
       {"name":"diameter_units", "value":"km"},
       {"name":"unspoiled","value":"no"}]}]},
 {"kind":"uninhabitable",
  "names": {"english":"Mars","french":"Mars"},
  "satellites" : [
    {"name":"Phobos",
     "parameters": [
       {"name":"diameter", "intValue":"2200"},
       {"name":"diameter_units", "value":"m"},
       {"name":"unspoiled","value":"yes"}]},
    {"name":"Deimos",
     "parameters": [
       {"name":"diameter", "intValue":"1200"},
       {"name":"diameter_units", "value":"m"},
       {"name":"unspoiled","value":"yes"}]}]}]}
```

Comment: What is the criteria for identifying `have been spoiled?`, i.e. there is no json record with name as `"spoiled"` in the above post

Comment: On second glance, do you mean `{"name":"unspoiled","value":"no"}` as the criterion?

Comment: Thanks! I figured it was going to be simple but powerful.
And yeah I could have worded it better; I was trying to think of something that duplicated the structure of my data. It reads like Don't Do What Donny Don't Does

Answer (score 2):

The program below selects planets whose moons have all been spoiled. As each *parameter* is a name-value pair, we can use `from_entries` to transform the array of parameters into an object and retrieve the *unspoiled* status with just `.unspoiled`, and thus avoid another `select` to find the parameter we're interested in.

```
.Planets[] | select(.satellites | all(.parameters | from_entries .unspoiled == "no")) .names.french
```

If a single spoiled moon is enough, change `all` to `any`.

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/BWoS6URuiI)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

And here, also a solution for the same JSON query using an alternative tool (`jtc`):

In the simplest form, the following will do:

```
bash $ <file.json jtc -w'[value]:<no>:[-5][names][french]'
"Terre"
```

However, that solution will return planet's french name for each of the moon, e.g., for spoiled moons it would give this:

```
bash $ <file.json jtc -w'[value]:<yes>:[-5][names][french]'
"Mars"
"Mars"
bash $
```

For the case when there're multiple moons but the name is required only once, strengthen the query like this (showcasing here spoiled moons):

```
bash $ <file.json jtc -w'<satellites>l:[value]:<yes>[-5][names][french]'
"Mars"
bash $
```

PS. I'm a deveoper of `jtc` unix JSON processor
PPS. the above disclaimer is required by SO.

#### Update:

the answer was updated based on discussion in comments with @oguzismail to enhance structural relationship between `value` and `french` labels so that other (irrelevant) possible `value` matches won't trigger false positives.
If, by a chance, the structural relation `[-5][names]` is not enough, the query then can be ultimately enhanced by inserting `<unspoiled>[-1]` before `[value]...` lexeme

Comment: Before I upvote this, what is `-5` for? You're not hardcoding the index of parameter `unspoiled`, right?

Comment: Oguz, in `jtc` negative indices provide addressing of parents from currently found elements toward the root. E.g.: -1 addresses an immediate parent, -2 - a parent of a parent, etc.  For given data structure, -5 is a depth required to get to the found `value` element to the parent holding `french`. Considering the structure of this JSON is fixed, hardcoding the _depth_ parameter is safe.

Comment: I agree that it is. What's bugging me is that I can't see `unspoiled` in any of these invocations. OP's sample doesn't contain any parameters that also take yes/no as value, but I'm not sure if assuming that the actual data aligns in that with the sample in the question is also safe.

Comment: The answer was provided based on a given sample. If the original JSON contain `value` label in other parts of JSON, the query can be easily enhanced by prepending `<unspoiled>[-1]`

Comment: Now that's nice, if I were you I would include that in my answer.

Comment: However, even if the original JSON contained `value` labels in other parts, most likely the query would work even w/o that enhancing: relation between the value and french labels is unique enough to ensure correctness of the query. You may try throwing random value labels - it’ll still work correctly.