# jq ignores else clause

Tags: json, if-statement, select, jq

I would like to search and replace a specific value in a json line-based data using jq and keep the object unmodified if the match is false.

Considering the following `input.json`:

```json
{"foo":{"bar":"one"}}
{"foo":{"bar":"two"}}
```

I tried the following statement, but the else clause is ignored, and therefore lines that don't match are lost:

```sh
jq -c '. | if (select(.foo.bar == "one")) then .foo.bar |= "ok" else . end' input.json
```

produces result:

```json
{"foo":{"bar":"ok"}}
```

The following command produces the right output:

```sh
jq -c '(. | select(.foo.bar == "one")).foo.bar = "ok"' input.json
```

desired output:

```json
{"foo":{"bar":"ok"}}
{"foo":{"bar":"two"}}
```

Why the first command fails to output the object `.` in the else clause?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select objects based on value of variable in object using jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18592173/select-objects-based-on-value-of-variable-in-object-using-jq)

Comment: No, this answer was using select and actually we have to use just a if statement as indicated by the accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `select`:

```
. | if .foo.bar == "one" then .foo.bar |= "ok" else . end
```

`select` is useful for filtering, but it doesn't return a false value if there's nothing to select, it doesn't return anything.

Comment: In other words, `if empty then 1 else 2 end` yields the empty stream.