# Test field against multiple values in select in JQ

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have a list of values that I want to select by in my JQ. That is, my JSON looks something like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "a"
    },
    {
        "id": "b"
    },
    {
        "id": "z"
    }
]
```

My list of values is something like `a b c`. This list is stored as a scalar variable in bash (not hardcoded). How can I select the corresponding objects from the JSON from this list of values?

I have seen other questions about using a value to select something in a JQ query, but before this I had not seen an example of selecting in JQ based on **multiple values**. e.g. Select JSON where they're in a given list of values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select objects based on value of variable in object using jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18592173/select-objects-based-on-value-of-variable-in-object-using-jq)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass the list of ids to JQ using the `--arg` directive, split it into an array there and keep that in a variable, and test whether an object's `id` field holds a value that resides in that array using the `IN` built-in.

```
var='a b c'
jq --arg ids "$var" '($ids / " ") as $ids
| .[] | select(.id | IN($ids[]))' file
```