# Finding the path to all occurrences of a specific key is a specify value

Tags: json, jq

I have a bunch of hundred thousand line json files, and I'm trying to work how out they are structured.

I'd like to print the path to all keys named "ENTITY" with a value "TEXT".

these can be nested at any level. There are lots of examples for finding one at a particular level, e.g. [Select objects based on value of variable in object using jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18592173/select-objects-based-on-value-of-variable-in-object-using-jq)

But I'm actually trying to figure out where these items are nested, since the file is so large, I can't do it by inspection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
paths( objects | .ENTITY == "TEXT" )
```

Format the output as desired. For example,

```sh
jq -r 'paths( objects | .ENTITY == "TEXT" ) | join(".")'
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/ROvYL27zwT)

---

[*The following consists of my original answer*]

```
path( .. | select( type == "object" and .ENTITY == "TEXT" ) )
```

Format the output as desired. For example,

```sh
jq -r 'path( .. | select( type =="object" and .ENTITY == "TEXT" ) ) | join(".")'
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/9J3HoJHamA)

Comment: Provided a simpler solution

Answer (score -1):

If I understood your question correctly, you are searching for leafs with a given key/field whose value matches a given value. This approach uses `leaf_paths` to get all leafs along with `getpath` to get their values, `transpose` to tuple them up, and finally `select` to reduce the list to those matching the criteria. The output is only the path arrays.

```
jq --arg key "ENTITY" --arg value "TEXT" '
  [[leaf_paths],[getpath(leaf_paths)]]
  | transpose
  | map(select(.[0][-1] == $key and .[1] == $value))[][0]
'
```

Comment: This answer also works. For some reason, ikegami's answer runs about 5 times as fast.

Comment: If I were to guess, it's because my approach filters early, whereas this approach constructs a huge number of arrays that will end up being discarded.

Comment: Tip: "`leaf_paths` is *deprecated* and will be removed in the next major release." Use `paths(scalars)` instead.

Comment: I think the approach you have in mind is closer to: `leaf_paths as $p | [$p, getpath($p)] | select(.[0][-1] == $key and .[1] == $value)`

Comment: That said, the above can be optimized to `paths(. == $value) | select(.[-1] == $key)`. I still prefer mine (`paths( objects | .ENTITY == "TEXT" )`), though. 1) It gives the path to the object rather than ending all paths with `ENTITY`. 2) It's cleaner. 3) It should also be faster by filtering out more sooner.