# Select objects based on value of variable in nested objects using jq

Tags: json, bash, jq, nested-object

My question is very similar to one found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18592173/select-objects-based-on-value-of-variable-in-object-using-jq) -

I have the following JSON

```
{
"FOO": {
    "id": "23432423",
    "Result": {
        "Status": "SUCCESS",
        "Reason": ""
    }
},
"BAR": {
    "id": "45345535",
    "Result": {
        "Status": "FAILURE",
        "Reason": ""
    }
},
"BAZ": {
    "id": "123432423",
    "Result": {
        "Status": "SUCCESS",
        "Reason": ""
          }
       }
    }
```

Using jq I wanted the original object format back filtering on status FAILED

Result:

```
"BAR": {
    "id": "45345535",
    "Result": {
        "Status": "FAILURE",
        "Reason": ""
    }
}
```

I tried both solutions suggested from above post
`to_entries | map(select(.value.Status=="FAILURE")) | from_entries` and `'with_entries(select(.value.Status =="FAILURE"))'` both are giving empty results. Going round and round. Any help apprecaited

Answer (score 2):

Your `Status` property is nested inside a `Result` object, but you are selecting `Status` directly. You must select on `.value.Result.Status`:

```
with_entries(select(.value.Result.Status == "FAIL"))
```

`map_values` is a bit shorter even:

```
map_values(select(.Result.Status == "FAIL"))
```

Output:

```json
{
  "BAR": {
    "id": "x....4",
    "Result": {
      "Status": "FAIL",
      "Reason": ""
    }
  }
}
```