# jq: filter array of objects based on condition

Tags: jq

I have an array of objects with a `tab_id` and `pane_id` fields.

I would like to return the `tab_id`s of the first object whose `pane_id` field matches the value of an environment variable.

I am also interested in returning the `tab_id` of only the first match

Here is a sample file :

```json
[
  {
    "tab_id": 0,
    "pane_id": 0,
  },
  {
    "tab_id": 0,
    "pane_id": 1,
  },
  {
    "tab_id": 0,
    "pane_id": 2,
  },
  {
    "tab_id": 1,
    "pane_id": 3,
  },
  {
    "tab_id": 2,
    "pane_id": 4,
  }
]
```

So in this case, if my environment variable is 2, I need the `tab_id` value of the object whose `pane_id` is 2, that is `0`

Comment: You'd be better off by providing a concrete example including a sample file, as currently it is, for example, underspecified what data types you are dealing with, what a "match" means in your case, etc. Filling in the gaps, you might be looking for something like `jq --arg fromenv "$envvar" 'first(.[] | select(.pane_id == $fromenv).tab_id)' input.json`

Comment: Consider the `--slurp` switch (load the full object graph - rather than operating on a stream) if you need to do any sorting before selecting the first item.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select objects based on value of variable in object using jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18592173/select-objects-based-on-value-of-variable-in-object-using-jq)

Comment: @pmf Sorry,I used nushell in the end and I forgot about this question. But I still think an answer would be interesting for other people. Thanks for your answer. It looks like exactly what I need except it does not seem to work on the example input I added.
Your solution almost works except for the environment variable part. It only works when I replace `$fromenv` directly with my variable's value else it does not work (I have of course replaced `$envvar` by the name of the variable I care about)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, omit object-final commas (before closing an object with `}`) as it is not valid JSON.

Then, your provided example shows how important they are. It revealed that your values are numbers, not strings. Therefore you have to import the external values as such. In case of numbers, using `--argjson` is appropriate.

```bash
$ q=0
$ jq --argjson id "$q" 'first(.[] | select(.pane_id == $id).tab_id)' input.json
0
```